# Multiple test configurations for surefire plugin

Tags: maven, junit, testng

I have an issue with my pom:

There are two types of tests running within the project:

Main set of tests using TestNG and JUnit code coverage tests. What I would like is to run JUnit tests on `test-compile` phase and do not run TestNG tests (which are run on `test` phase) if previous failed.

As of now I have the following which runs only TestNG:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.17</version>
    <configuration>
        <argLine>
            -javaagent:${settings.localRepository}/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/1.8.4/aspectjweaver-1.8.4.jar
        </argLine>
        <properties>
            <property>
                <name>listener</name>
                <value>org.uncommons.reportng.HTMLReporter, org.uncommons.reportng.JUnitXMLReporter</value>
            </property>
        </properties>
        <suiteXmlFiles>
            <suiteXmlFile>src/test/_all.xml</suiteXmlFile>
        </suiteXmlFiles>
        <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

I tried to play with `<execution>` tag but I can't provide path to TestNG suite then. Any ideas how to combine these tests using surefire plugin and specify different goals?

Answer (score 1):

Solution was to add maven-failsafe-plugin separately from maven-surefire-plugin.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.17</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
            <artifactId>surefire-junit47</artifactId>
            <version>2.17</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <configuration>
        <includes>
            <include>junitcodecoverage/**Test.java</include>
        </includes>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>integration-test</id>
            <phase>test-compile</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>integration-test</goal>
                <goal>verify</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```